# JsonElement to Native C# Object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have a function which takes in an argument as `IDictionary<string, object>` parameters.
This argument value is passed from a request argument from API.

**ExecuteQueryRequest.cs**

```
public class ExecuteQueryRequest
{
    public string QueryId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string TenantId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

public sealed class ExecuteQueryRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<ExecuteQueryRequest>
{
    public ExecuteQueryRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.QueryId)
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.TenantId)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

I am using Ardalis.Endpoint class. The issue is when the i get request.Parameters the dictionary's values are `object` but internally they are still `JsonElement`.

I am using this parameters variable to Dapper's `QueryAsync()` method which results in an error giving a message `System.Text.JsonElement cannot be used as parameter value`.

I tackled this issue by using a ConversionFunction

**Function:**

```
private object? GetNativeTypeFromJsonElement(JsonElement jsonElement)
{
    switch (jsonElement.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Number:
            if (jsonElement.TryGetInt64(out long lValue))
            {
                return lValue;
            }
            else if (jsonElement.TryGetDouble(out double doubleValue))
            {
                return doubleValue;
            }
            else if (jsonElement.TryGetDecimal(out decimal decimalValue))
            {
                return decimalValue;
            }
            return null;
        case JsonValueKind.String:
            return jsonElement.GetString() ?? "";
        case JsonValueKind.True:
            return true;
        case JsonValueKind.False:
            return false;
        case JsonValueKind.Array:
            List<object> arrayValues = new List<object>();
            foreach (var element in jsonElement.EnumerateArray())
            {
                var value = GetNativeTypeFromJsonElement(element);
                if (value is not null)
                {
                    arrayValues.Add(value);
                }
            }
            return arrayValues;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

This is working for me. Because I didn't came across any `JsonSerializer` function. which does the same thing.

I am looking for better solutions which i may have missed or serializer function i can use `out of the box`.

Comment: *I am looking for better solutions which i may have missed or serializer function i can use `out of the box`.* -- there aren't any.  As stated in the MSFT documentation page [Deserialize inferred types to object properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties), *When deserializing to a property of type `object`, a `JsonElement` object is created... **For scenarios that require type inference, the following code shows a custom converter for `object` properties.***